# docker-compose linking mysql and php containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a docker-compose as follow:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: lap
    volumes:
      - ./webroot:/var/www/app
      - ./configs/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./configs/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

    links:
      - dbs:mysql
  dbs:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./configs/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

`docker --version`

> Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

`docker-compose --version`

> docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb

`lsb_release -a`

> No LSB modules are available.
>   Distributor ID:   Debian
>   Description:  Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
>   Release:  8.10
>   Codename: jessie

If I run following commands and check /etc/host on php container I see no linking ( which I see when I do docker container --link )

`docker-compose up -d
 docker exec -it web_1 bash
 root@web_1> cat /etc/hosts`

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> ::1   localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>
> fe00::0   ip6-localnet
>
> ff00::0   ip6-mcastprefix
>
> ff02::1   ip6-allnodes
>
> ff02::2   ip6-allrouters
>
> 172.18.0.3    9c401ea7d031

The `dbs` container is assigned `127.18.0.2` ip address, what I was expecting was something like this in above `/etc/hosts`

> 127.18.0.2   dbs mysql

I see the same behavior in one of my Mac OSX system , probably I am doing something wrong or missing anything ?

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your mounts? This blog helped me really to make my connection work, although it's about postgres and not mysql: https://lvthillo.com/create-simple-php-app-using-postgresql-in-docker-compose/

Comment: Try to ping "dbs" or "mysql" from web container. They are supposed to be accessible by only service name. In my case, I saw my links alias is working though it's not `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul please make that an answer , thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers are accessible by `service-name` from docker-compose. `links` of docker-compose is just an alias of this service-name. It supposed to be reachable from same network either by `service-name` or `alias-name`.

In your case:

try to ping from `web` to `dbs` or `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy container links are deprecated and will be removed some time in the future from docker. The problem at hand is that you want your web container talk to your db container.

The solution is simple.

- Use environmental variables to dynamically define database access DB_HOST.
- Load this environment in your app, and if this variable is not defined then as a fallback value use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Assuming that's done, you can now do this on your compose...

You can now define `DB_HOST=dbs` in your dockerfile.

```
version: '3.2'
    services:
      web:
          build: .
          image: lap
          volumes:
             - ./webroot:/var/www/app
             - ./configs/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
             - ./configs/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
          environment:
             - DB_HOST=dbs
      dbs:
          image: mysql
          ports:
             - "3307:3306"
          environment:
             - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          volumes:
             - ./configs/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
             - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

This will fix this conundrum.

Comment: I think they are still valid in the context of  `docker-compose` probably they are deprecated for `docker run` please check the link https://forums.docker.com/t/are-links-deprecated-in-docker-compose/27348/2